# How to implement specific type of protocol in a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol named ViperPresenterProtocol that contains a property protocol named ViperInteractorProtocol.

Now, I want to have another protocol that extends ViperPresenterProtocol and returns a different type.
But, when a class confirm to the TestPresenterProtocol, I want to implement only the TestInteractorProtocol.

```
protocol ViperInteractorProtocol {}
protocol TestInteractorProtocol: ViperInteractorProtocol {}

protocol ViperPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: ViperInteractorProtocol? { get set }
}

protocol TestPresenterProtocol2: ViperPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: TestInteractorProtocol? { get set }
}

class TestPresenter: TestPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: TestInteractorProtocol?  //  Compile error
    var interactor: ViperInteractorProtocol?  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the child-protocol `TestPresenterProtocol` extend it's definition and conform to the parent-protocol requirement would allow you to create class that conforms to the child-protocol to only have the requirements for child-protocol and not the parent-protocol. The only requirement that's needed for that is the compiler must be able to distinguish between the properties. With the same name in this case `interactor` confuses the compiler. Hope this will help you in some way.

```
protocol ViperInteractorProtocol { }
protocol TestInteractorProtocol: ViperInteractorProtocol { }

protocol ViperPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: ViperInteractorProtocol? { get set }
}

protocol TestPresenterProtocol: ViperPresenterProtocol {
    var testInteractor: TestInteractorProtocol? { get set }
}

extension TestPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: ViperInteractorProtocol? {
        set { interactor = newValue }
        get { testInteractor }
    }
}

class TestPresenter: TestPresenterProtocol {
    var testInteractor: TestInteractorProtocol?
}
```